# Why Doctor Carmack didn't wait for Patricia while closing the door?

Tags: plot-explanation, doom-2005

In Doom (2005), In opening scene, Scientists are attacked by some monster in science facility, So all scientist running for their life & Doctor Carmack entered into control room started closing the door.

While closing the door, he didn't wait for fellow doctor Patricia to come **even he saw her coming**, so her hand stuck in door & she eventually died & turned into monster later.

[image]

Comment: Probably panic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Panic & Self-Preservation

He's **running for his life**.

He doesn't care about anyone else or anything else except saving his own life and warning Earth of the security breach and getting the quarantine implemented.